# Try to find the number of points near the black color ؟

Tags: image-processing, image, output

Given this `RGB` image

[image]

I want to find the number of points that are, or almost, black ؟

Comment: Please double check your question.

Comment: I cannot find the ؟. Moreover, what does "near" mean?

Comment: Point Near to black color or give me black don’t worry

Comment: One approach: binarize the image, then count the number of zeros in the binarized image.

Comment: `(yourimage)// Binarize // ImageData // Flatten // Counts`

Comment: similarly, `(yourimage)// Binarize // ColorNegate // Total`

Comment: Worth mentioning that Binarize has a threshold argument, so you can adjust what you consider to be a black pixel.

Answer (score 3):

First let's convert to grayscale and look at the histogram of colors.

```
im = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPKeW.jpg"];
gdata = Join @@ ImageData[ColorConvert[im, "Grayscale"]];
Histogram[gdata]
```

[image]

We see there's a big divide between 'black' and 'white', so we can just binarize and count the black pixels.

```
Length @ PixelValuePositions[Binarize[im], 0]
```

> ```
> 49073
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the image is RGB

```
Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPKeW.jpg", "ColorSpace"]
```

> RGBColor

This gives the positions of the pixels with RGB values from `{0,0,0}` to `{10,10,10}`. Change the [`Round`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Round.html) argument to redefine what "almost black" means.

```
Position[
 Round[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPKeW.jpg", "Data"], 10]
 , {0, 0, 0}
 ]
```

Then you can use [`Length`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Length.html)